# Determining percent land coverage around points of interest using NLCD and QGIS

Tags: qgis, nlcd

A former grad student was working on a project using ArcGIS to calculate land coverage (specifically water) around the breeding location of a threatened bird species. His zones went out 3, 10, 17, and 24km from each location. The reviewers have now asked for 1) zones up to 100km and 2) forest/grassland distinctions.

I have zero experience with GIS, and my former grad student is a new parent, trying to work, etc, so I’m sort of on my own. Can anyone give me the QGIS for dummies that will allow me to do this type of analysis? I have downloaded the NLCD and some shapefiles which apparently contain the coordinates for all locations. As a back up, I have all coordinates in excel as well. When I import his shapefile as a vector layer and try to add buffers, I’m only able to select degrees (not km) and the buffers are ovals instead of round. Ideally, I’d like to be able to extract the percent coverage for each category in NLCD for a few different radii.

Comment: might be helpful for starting point https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfjg_jpgiTE

Comment: There are a lot of ways for someone new to GIS to go wrong. It might be worth your while to find a GIS student to double-check your methods. It would be really embarrassing to have a paper published, and only later find out that you made a really basic GIS error and all your numbers are wrong. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I most definitely am going to run this by the university’s GIS professional when he comes back from sabbatical!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, add a basemap to your QGIS project. You can add a basemap by installing the QuickMapServices plugin and adding a layer from the new QMS toolbar, eg, Google Maps or Open Street Map. Confirm that the shapefile data is located correctly relative the basemap. If it's not, disregard the rest of my answer.

The `buffer` tool in QGIS uses the same units as the layer's coordinate reference system (CRS). Your shapefile is currently in a CRS that uses degrees. You should re-project it into a CRS which

1. uses meters as its units,
2. is an *equal-area* CRS, and
3. is appropriate to the scale and location of the data.

You could use http://epsg.io/ to help find an appropriate CRS. However, since your grad student already created some buffers, they must have already chosen a CRS. If they documented their methods, the CRS used for creating the buffers *should* be written down somewhere. It might be in a text file called "metadata.txt" or an xml file stored with the GIS data. Look also for the phrase "spatial reference system" (SRS), which is used interchangably with the phrase "coordinate reference system" (CRS).

If you can't find the CRS documented, ask your former grad student. It should be a quick question for them to answer. If they can't answer that question, there's a good chance that they're not competent at GIS, and you should be suspicious of their original results.

Once you figure out what CRS you want to use, *re-project* the shapefile layer into that CRS. *Don't* change the CRS in the layer properties. Instead, re-project it by right clicking on the layer name in the layer panel > Export > Export features as... to open the Export layer window. Choose your desired CRS from the dropdown menu. Choose the option to add the new layer to the project.

Use the re-projected layer to calculate buffers. Remember that the buffer units are now meters, so multiply your kilometer measurements by 1000.

Follow the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfjg_jpgiTE) recommended by Mapperz to calculate land cover percentage by area.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to do as you said and I am watching the tutorial video, but my next question would be of the files I download with the NLCD, only the .img file will open in QGIS, and I am not seeing the attribute table as the video shows with individual features (water, grassland, etc) available to chose. Do I need to do some sort of processing with the .img file to make that work? Thanks again!

Comment: The .img file wouldn't have an attribute table, but I can't tell you which file would without knowing what the other options are. I recommend posting this as a separate question. List all the files (and their file extensions, eg .shp, .img, etc) that you got when you downloaded the NLCD.